# Line based chunking by size?

Tags: split

[Github restricts file uploads to 100mb](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota/). This is unfortunate for public data. I know I can split binary files with `dd`.  What I would like to do is split them all into 99MB files but here's the catch, I don't want to split on a line -- **only a newline**. Is there an easy way to split up files into chunks based on their size, but not to mid-line.

## Example

```
#/bin/sh
for i in $(seq 1 1000000); do
  echo "This is a test sentence." >> file
done;
```

Now `file` is 26MB. I would like that file to be split into 1 MB chunks, but never split anywhere **but** only a line-boundary (`\n`).

Comment: See also [What is the difference between split -C and split -b?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/421267)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I missed this in the docs, so in the event this helps anyone else

> `-C`, `--line-bytes=SIZE` put at most SIZE bytes of records per output file

Just ignore `-n, --number=CHUNKS` I didn't have to use that anyway.